# Mean Value Theorem ( i guess )

Tags: derivatives

Suppose that a function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$ and that $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for every $x \in [0,1]$. Show that there must exist a number $c$ such that $f(c)=c.$

Comment: IVT on $f(x)-x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Hint$: remember that when you have a continuos function defined on an interval, you can apply the intermediate value theorem. if $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for each $x\in [0, 1]$, what can you say about the function $h: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ defined by $h(x) = f(x) - x$?

Comment: why h(x) is equal to 0 ?  i am really confused about this theorem :D

Comment: You should really try to solve this one yourself, it's a classic exercise of a decent calculus course. I'll give you another hint. Do different cases. What happens if $h(0) = 0$ or $h(1) = 0$? What happens if this is not the case? Give the intermediate value theorem another look.

Comment: thank you :))))